# input 2d array sideways

Tags: c#, arrays

how can I input an integer array sideways not downward? suppose it has array [2,2] then in c # :

**input :**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**I want to store like this:**

```
1 2
3 4
```

what should i do? I am confused, as for the code I use:

```
int length = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] box = new int[length, 2];
for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<2; j++){
        photo[i, j] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(String[] args){
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] box = new int[length, 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        box[i, 0] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        box[i, 1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

As you have mentioned that you have two columns it might give you a better understanding.For each row since we have two columns due to that I we are fetching values two times.

Comment: I understand what OP wants to do.He wants to fill the array horizontally.

Comment: It was my mistake. Deleted my other comments.

Comment: Dont forgot that you want only half of the length.
length / 2